# How to change this first person sentence to third person

Tags: third-person

I am having trouble with not using the first person in a sentence. I know that the first person sentences have "I", "We", "Us", and whatnot. But that is my problem. I am trying to change my sentence towards a third person.

My sentence:

> In my opinion towards the articles, I both agree on the point of view towards society.

Comment: Do you see which words need to change?

Comment: I don't understand what *I both agree* means in this context. It sounds like you have two personalities, and both of them agree—but that can't be right. I suspect you want to change that to ***we*** *both agree*, but the single sentence doesn't make explicit the number of people present. Also, why make it in the third person if you're talking about yourself?

Comment: "[....], I agree on the points of view of both (the) articles." - is that what you're after?

Comment: That can't be done, because the example simply does not make sense. That's partly because the word "both" has no place. If it did, dropping it would change something. In fact, how is "In my opinion towards the articles, I agree on the point of view towards society" any different?

If it did work, you might try something like "In our opinion towards the articles, we (both) agree on the point of view towards society" but that would be harder to understand, not easier.

Why d'you think this is about persons, rather than the actual meaning?

Can you find a better example?